# R rolling %between%

Tags: r, data.table

Looking for kind of rolling `%between%` function.
In case if there is no exactly matching values on the edges of between call then it would take a next value (if possible).
Example, lets call the function `%between1%`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2015-06-28","2015-06-30","2015-07-04","2015-07-05","2015-07-05")),
                 val = letters[1:5])
dt[date %between% as.Date(c("2015-07-02","2015-07-05"))]
#          date val
# 1: 2015-07-04   c
# 2: 2015-07-05   d
# 2: 2015-07-05   e
dt[date %between% as.Date(c("2015-07-02","2015-07-05")), roll=TRUE] # no effect
#          date val
# 1: 2015-07-04   c
# 2: 2015-07-05   d
# 2: 2015-07-05   e


dt[date %between1% as.Date(c("2015-07-02","2015-07-05"))]
### expected output:
#          date val
# 1: 2015-06-30   b
# 1: 2015-07-04   c
# 2: 2015-07-05   d
# 2: 2015-07-05   e
```

Looking for a high performance solution of `%between1%`, it should be somehow possible using binary search and rolling.

Comment: actually I need to have a next *by group*, this would complicate